# Circlular Convolution for two finite sequences of different length.

Tags: fourier-analysis

Hello.
I just want to know how the  circlular Convolution for two finite sequences of different lengths is defined.
As I have found in MIT lectures for the sequences of the same length we have

$C=\sum_{m=0}^{N-1}x_1[(m)\%N]*x_2[(n-m)\%N]*R_N{(n)}$

Where R is rectangular window of the width N (it means we extract one period from the periodic sequence we get),where N is the period of both input sequences.

But what is N if the lengths (or periods)of the input sequences are different?

I would appreciate some official confirmations for the correct answer.

Comment: There is no "correct" answer -- it depends on what you are using this for.

Comment: I met this on my digital signal processing exam(the question was the length of the output sequence).
So,do you know any possible uses of it?


Comment: My unofficial best guess is that the length is some divisor of the product of the two lengths of the sequences, perhaps the minimal such length that has a whole number of periods from each sequence.
Gerhard "Six Plus Three Equals Two?" Paseman, 2012.01.13

Comment: In signal processing you usually pad the shorter sequence by zero.